# How do I make my snake in my game to be just one character insted of printing all over the console in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm attempting to make a snake game with C# in the console app. I managed to make the player (snake), the grid or area of the playground, the random food spawner, and collisions of the walls of the grid or playground and food, so every time the snake touches the food, it dissapears and spawns in other random location inside of the playground.

Now the next thing to do is to make my snake to be just 1 char, and everytime it eats the food to add 1 more char to it, so it turns into a 2 char snake... and so on, just how the classic snake game works. Right now, the snake is just 1 char, but it prints all over the console when I move it.

How do I do this? I'm kinda stuck and I've read a lot of others people code and explanation, and they talk about FIFO stack, or a queue. Do I need to delete all of my current code of the player (snake) and recreat from scratch using this type of collection? Here is the main code of the player, the other classes are just for the grid or area, console windows resizing and a simple beeping sound whenever the snake eats the food.

I am a complete begginer and this is my first time doing something like this, so if you find a rookie mistake please tell me so I can get better at it. Thank you!

```
public class Player
{
    private Grid grid = new Grid();
    private int x = 38;
    private int y = 10;
    private Random random1 = new Random();
    private Random random2 = new Random();
    private int foodx = 0;
    private int foody = 0;

    public void Play()
    {
        const char toWrite = '*';

        Write(toWrite, x, y);
        grid.Create();

        while (true)
        {
            foodx = random1.Next(1, 79);
            foody = random1.Next(1, 19);
            SpawnFood();

            while (x != foodx || y != foody)
            {
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    var command = Console.ReadKey().Key;

                    switch (command)
                    {
                        case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                            if (y > 1)
                                y--;
                            break;
                        case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                            if (y < 19)
                                y++;
                            break;
                        case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                            if (x < 78)
                                x++;
                            break;
                        case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                            if (x > 1)
                                x--;
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("That key is not avilable");
                            break;
                    }
                    Write(toWrite, x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Write(char toWrite, int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write('*');
        }
    }

    public void SpawnFood()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(foodx, foody);
        Console.Write('O');
        BeepSound.Do();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: You're mostly there.  In your `Write` method, use the char you are passing: `Console.Write(toWrite);` instead of `Console.Write('*');`  Then right above your `switch (command)` line, add `Write(' ', x, y);`

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you!!! Now all I need to do is add another char everytime my snake eats something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a little different, and more complicated.  I'm just erasing the previous character before you change the x or y coordinate.  You will need a `Queue<T>` to handle that.  I would create a `Point` class to hold your x and y coordinates, too, to make it easier to hold your coordinate data.

Comment: Yeah I've realized that, but seeing my console clean made me happy since I've been stuck with this problem for hours lmao.

Comment: At some point, you'll discover it's easier to clear and render a whole screen on each change.